# Javascript sweep line algorithm finding all elements with the same x coordinate

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to implement line sweep algorithm by using **PURE** Javascript (no other frameworks) that basically scans through the screen from left to right and looks all the elements (including overlapped elements) that share the same x coordinate.

For example

[image: I have 6 div with border layout randomly on the screen, and I am using a vertical line (blue dotted line) to scan through it from left to right.]

I have 6 `div` elements with black border, and they all layout randomly on the screen. for illustration purposes I am using a vertical dotted blue line to scan through across the plane from left to right. The goal is that report all the elements that the line passed over . For the example above, how do we report that `Div A`, `Div E`, `Div D` and also the `hyperlink D` within `Div D` by using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the position of elements with the [`getBoundingClientRect` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect). Then loop over them and check whether they match your scanning:

```
var all = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var x = /* blue line */;
var match = [];
for (var i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
    var rect = all[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.left < x && rect.right > x)
        match.push(all[i]);
});
```

Shorter, functional way:

```
var match = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.body.querySelectorAll("*"), function(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.left < x && rect.right > x;
});
```

If you need a quick-access function for often use, you would store all elements (with their coordinates) in a sorted data structure, a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree), where you can search for them.

Also, when it is guaranteed that child nodes of DOM elements do not exceed their parents boundaries, you can easily use the DOM itself as a search tree:

```
var x = /* the blue line */;
var match = function find(el, set) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.left < x && rect.right > x) {
        set.push(el);
        for (var i=0; i<el.children.length; i++)
            find(el.children[i]);
    }
    return set;
}(document.body, []);
```

Comment: Just a note: `getElementsByTagName("*")` is [way faster](http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname/25) than `querySelectorAll("*")` (plus, you can use `document.all` if present). And I wouldn't use `filter`, just a simple `for`. But this all depends if the task is performance critical.

Comment: The querySelector seems to be boosted in Opera :-) Surely a loop would have done it, but I like functional programming...

Comment: I am wondering does it always has to retrieve all do the elements and then does an iteration through it one by one ? because you know it could be thousand of DOM elements to iterate through i mean. Is there a way to get back let says in sorted order by coordinates and then do a binary search something like that ?

Comment: @Bergi Whoa, Opera's performance with `querySelectorAll` are impressive, indeed. Apparently, they did something completely different - and very efficient, too. I wasn't aware of that. If only they could do the same for `getElementsByTagName`... And BTW, I love functional programming too, but... I seldom use it because it's too damn slow compared to classic iterations :(

Comment: @user1389813 Why would you want to sort the elements, really? They can be 10, or 1000, or one million, but you'd still have a 5-lines loop. The problem with sorting is that it's way slower because it has to iterate through all the elements, in most cases more than onece, and make a comparison each time. And how would you sort them? By the left coordinate? Or right? Or middle point? And then, how would you use the binary search? So, why don't you just apply the test case and get all the elements you want with a single loop?

Comment: I mean if you don't sort, you are comparing all the DOM elements every time, isn't it ? I mean you need to do that again as soon as the blue vertical line moves 1px away. With sorting by x coordinate, and certainly only one time, then we can just do a binary search looking for x coordinate that the vertical line is currently at like a look up

Comment: @user1389813 If you think about it sorting here to apply binary search leads to big mistakes, because there's no unique way to tell when an element is "greater" than another. For example, what's "greater" between an element and its parent? The element, because its left coordinate is greater, or the parent, because the right coordinate is greater? If you're worried about checking coordinates each time the line moves, just store the element coordinates like Diodeus said.

Comment: The child will be 1px away from its parent... I tried  el.getBoundingClientRect().left for the parent div and the child hyper link. For example the example above...div D margin-left:300px, and the hyper link D (its child) will be 301px when you call getVoundingClientRect().left

Comment: @Bergi - in your shorter version with the `filter` `all[i]` is not defined. you probably mean `el.getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: @Bergi - btw, how does the "shorter" version checks for overlaps? (same x cords with another area) I'm struggling with the logic in this one..seems areas aren't being compared with each-other

Comment: @vsync: None of my codes compares areas with each other, it just finds all elements which intersect with the line at position `x`.

Comment: @Bergi - right, my bad. Do you have any idea how can you check both X and Y (in the filter method), when the aspect ratio isn't `1` ? seems straightforward when it's `1` but when it's not.. It would also be mental to scan every X position...very heavy. I am looking for a more performant solution

Answer (score 1):

1. Gather all of the DOM elements
2. [Find their positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630338/using-javascript-to-find-position-of-dom-elements) and stash them in an array (so you can use the data again without going through the DOM)
3. Loop through the array and solve for x